# Include all imports in Air application Bundle?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flash-builder

How can I import all files and classes into my AIR bundle... it must take a note that I created first a flex project, and set it's main class as Actionscript (.as) .

When I build a release all my imports (org) etc.. are not included in the .AIR installer... i have checked this by installing the app and then after show package contents, notice that the diretory structure exists but it doesn't include any of other .as used as imports...

```
import org.papervision3d.cameras.Camera3D;
import org.papervision3d.materials.BitmapFileMaterial;
import org.papervision3d.materials.utils.MaterialsList;
import org.papervision3d.objects.DisplayObject3D;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i throw them in the lib folder... that's it

Answer (score 0):

Find very difficult to understand your problem. You want to include your source AS files in your application installer?

Why do you need that?

Comment: Because otherwise my swfs don't work properly, i created a project purely in AS3 and deployed it in AIR, now i need to include files in the bundle... how do i do that? is there any way to tell the compiler to include files in the bundle from a specific location?